# removing text from richtextbox

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I have  richtextbox1 and want to remove all the ***"USER1".*** from below , if sentence starts with ALTER TABLE and consists "USER1". what is the best way to do that using C#

***my text on richtextbox***

```
DROP INDEX XIE2TBL_A;

DROP INDEX XPKTBL_A;

ALTER TABLE "COURSE" DROP CONSTRAINT "CRSE_CRSE_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID") REFERENCES "USER1"."STUDENT"("STUDENT_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "USER1"."SECTION"("SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" DROP CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" DROP CONSTRAINT "GR_GRTW_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "USER1"."ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_GRTW_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") REFERENCES "USER1"."GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT"("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" DROP CONSTRAINT "GRTW_GRTYP_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" DROP CONSTRAINT "GRTW_SECT_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" ADD CONSTRAINT "GRTW_GRTYP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("GRADE_TYPE_CODE") REFERENCES "USER1"."GRADE_TYPE"("GRADE_TYPE_CODE") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" ADD CONSTRAINT "GRTW_SECT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "USER1"."SECTION"("SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "INSTRUCTOR" DROP CONSTRAINT "INST_ZIP_FK";

ALTER TABLE "INSTRUCTOR" ADD CONSTRAINT "INST_ZIP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ZIP") REFERENCES "USER1"."ZIPCODE"("ZIP") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "SECTION" DROP CONSTRAINT "SECT_INST_FK";
```

***I want this:***

```
  DROP INDEX XIE2TBL_A;

DROP INDEX XPKTBL_A;

ALTER TABLE "COURSE" DROP CONSTRAINT "CRSE_CRSE_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("STUDENT_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "SECTION"("SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" DROP CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" DROP CONSTRAINT "GR_GRTW_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_GRTW_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") REFERENCES "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT"("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" DROP CONSTRAINT "GRTW_GRTYP_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" DROP CONSTRAINT "GRTW_SECT_FK";

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" ADD CONSTRAINT "GRTW_GRTYP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("GRADE_TYPE_CODE") REFERENCES "GRADE_TYPE"("GRADE_TYPE_CODE") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT" ADD CONSTRAINT "GRTW_SECT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "SECTION"("SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "INSTRUCTOR" DROP CONSTRAINT "INST_ZIP_FK";

ALTER TABLE "INSTRUCTOR" ADD CONSTRAINT "INST_ZIP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ZIP") REFERENCES "ZIPCODE"("ZIP") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "SECTION" DROP CONSTRAINT "SECT_INST_FK";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `richTextBox1.Text` we don't need to check if each line starts with `ALTER TABLE` just do this:

```
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("REFERENCES \"USER1\".", "REFERENCES ");
```

If you want to check the `ALTER TABLE`, use a little of `RegEx`:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"USER1\"[.](.+)");
richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2");
```

Comment: what is the s.  stands forÉ

Comment: @user2661591 `s` is your input string.

Comment: I used like this but didnt work;   string s = richTextBox1.Text;
                        if (s.StartsWith("ALTER TABLE"))
                            s = s.Replace("REFERENCES \"USER1\".", "REFERENCES ");

Comment: @user2661591 `s` is not your `richTextBox.Text`, it's just a line in your `richTextBox`.

Comment: @user2661591 I updated my answer accordingly to your update. It should work now.

Comment: Unrecognized escape sequence at  s+

Comment: @user2661591 added \ before the \s+ in `Regex`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
        public string Remove(string statement, string toRemove)
    {
        int start = statement.IndexOf(toRemove);
        int end = toRemove.Length;
        statement = statement.Remove(start, end);
        return statement;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (line.Split(' ')[0] == "ALTER" && line.Split(' ')[1] == "TABLE" && line.Contains("USER1"))
            {
                int start = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(line);
                int end = line.Length - 1;
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(start, end).Insert(start, Remove(line, "\"USER1\"."));
            }
        }
    }
```

This should work, I already tested it.

Comment: Sorry, try it now. I messed up the substring numbers, and I couldn't test it btw.

Comment: Cannot assign to 'line' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: Right, I was doing this really late at night on my phone, but hopefully I can fully fix it now.